# Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, http

A few questions about python's quick and easy http server module.

Is it secure?
It is only available to people on my lan, right? If somebody typed in my public ip xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8000 it wouldn't work?

Comment: further to what memctrl said, you can use a port scanning site like grc shields up to make sure that it's not open to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http server(whether python or any http server) would work over your LAN but wouldn't work over the internet. For it to work over the Internet you have to set your router to do so

Eg. 
a) You have port forwarded an external port to your internal IP and port 8000.

b) You have set your internal IP as a DMZ host in your router settings.

Comment: -1 Be more clear, so that your answer reads in a self contained way. e.g. The http server(whether python or any http server) would work over your LAN but wouldn't work over the internet "unless of course you have setup port forwarding on your modem-router OR have your PC setup as a DMZ host"

Comment: you only improved formatting. See my comment.. You wrote "It wouldn't work"  The reader might then wonder What wouldn't work. I have edited your answer removing the "It wouldn't work" and replacing it with something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Python simplehttpserver or http.server (python 3) will be listening to every interface. Other guy -> Your router -> Your server.

Here's the bit that saves you. (Answer is yes, it won't work if you have not port forwarded and DMZ'd)

Your router has filters that block ports. You'll have to manually allow ports if you want your server to be seen from the world.

Your router probably also has a section that says "DMZ" or DeMilitarizedZone. Apart from port forwarding (allowing ports through filter), you will also need to DMZ your own computer, or whichever device is hosting the server. To do so, simply put your computer IP in the DMZ.

Note: It may be handy to have a static IP in the case if you DMZ your computer.

Also if you really don't want the internet at your doorstep, use host as `"127.0.0.1"` rather than `"0.0.0.0"`.

Example Test:

```
from socket import *
a = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
a.bind(('0.0.0.0',8000))
a.listen(1)
b,c = a.accept()

#Port tester can detect and the program receives the connection.

d = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
d.bind(('127.0.0.1',8000))
d.listen(1)
e,f = d.accept()

#Port tester cannot detect and the program receives no connection.
```

Comment: Great that you decided to try to answer a question, but please explain why one shouldn't think that you just reworded MemCtrl's answer 1.5 years later? In other words, what additional information does your answer have, if any? BTW, both answers failed to address the slight possibility that the OP's router is not performing NAT and thus the box running the HTTP server has the public IP assigned to it. Then the answer to the privacy question is not a "no" anymore. (ok, that is not likely the OP's case, but still...)

Comment: Good point, revised my answer.